# Input text file whitout header

Tags: hadoop, hive, create-table, hiveddl

I don't know which table properties I have to use for input text file without header. My text file only has one column.

I have this example:

```
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
    '/grusers/Fin/Ext/M/_Do'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "skip.header.line.count"="1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no header, then remove this property: "skip.header.line.count"="1"

Also instead of

```
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

you can specify `STORED AS TEXTFILE`.

Finally your code will look like this:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name (
   col_name string 
 )
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '/grusers/Fin/Ext/M/_Do'
```